# AutoComplete Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I am stuck in my code, I need to perfor autocomplete for States.
I already put the script libraries and no console error has been detect.
so what can i do.any suggestion.

This is my code:
Jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var states = [
        "Alabana",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California"];

    $('.mdb-autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source:states
    });
      });
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="quickmsg" id="quickmsg">
 <!-- Modal Subscription -->
<div class="modal fade modal-ext" id="modal-subscription" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">MessageBox </h4>
            </div>
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p></p>
                <br>
                <div class="md-form">
                    <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                    <input type="search" id="form22" name="State" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete">
                    <label for="form22">State name</label>
                </div>

                <div class="md-form">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="form32" name="Message" class="form-control">
                    <label for="form32">Your Message</label>
                </div>

                <div class="text-xs-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your implementation?

Comment: AutoComplete not working !!!!

Comment: you 3 word exact explication doesn't work for me

Comment: use google library for jquery

Comment: can you tell me which one ?

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Except this line $('document').ready(); I never seen document as string. so try to write it without qutoes  $(document).ready();

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

Comment: $(document).ready() working fine so there is no issue in that

Comment: Your code is working for me... did you added JQuery and JQueryUI? see this [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/foqemomaqi/1)

Comment: i already add up the librabry

Comment: Actually js is working fine but css is not working...

Comment: @user3286576 http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css add this css

Answer (score 1):

here is working jsfiddle demo you can write in it a and it display related "a" state..please check and add ui js and css.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/milan9898/z8m0tjuz/1/)

```
$("body").on("focus", ".mdb-autocomplete", function() {
var states = [
        "Alabana",
        "Alaska",
        "Arizona",
        "Arkansas",
        "California"];
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: states,
        minLength:0,
        }); 
        return false;
    }).bind('focus', function(){ $(this).autocomplete("search"); } );
```

add this script after jquery and min js.
 //code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js